# File access difference for php file running with cron vs browser

Tags: php, file, cron

A php file (say example.php) should write something into another file (say alma.txt). If example.php is run via a cron job, everything is ok, but when I call it through the browser, it does not write to alma.txt. Why?

Comment: please post the scrip and error messages.

Comment: I enabled error reporting (error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');) but no any error :(

Comment: This is a security feature. The account the web server uses doesnt have appropriate write permissions

Comment: either change the permissions of the Apache user account or the alma.txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cron job runs under the user that owns the crontab file that have the cron job configured.

When you run your php from the cron daemon, is your user the one that is executing the command.

When you run your php script through the browser. in the web server this script is executed by the user that launched the apache process. In ubuntu is the user www-data for example.

This looks like a file permission issue. Just to be sure grant all permission to the file alma.txt.

```
chmod 777 alma.txt
```

and try again, if everything is ok, then was a permission issue, and i will suggest you to set the right permissions to the file. Maybe add the group www-data to the file and grant 775 to it.